# Verifying Google Identity OAuth2 token with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have a Rails API with a variety of frontend clients.

I’m setting up Google Sign-in/up with OAuth2 (via Google Identity), and am having issues verifying the token that comes from Google - it seems simple with Python/Java/Node.js/PHP ([see their docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token)), but with Ruby it is proving difficult.

For context, my basic flow is:

1. Authentication button gets clicked on the client.
2. User completes authentication with Google, who redirects the request back to my Rails API, with the user’s email and a token.
3. Rails API searches for existing user with that email; if they exist, we authenticate them. If not, we create a new user with that email and then authenticate them.

I’m trying to verify the token in order to make sure that the request isn’t fake, i.e. someone/something pretending to be Google.

I’ve tried hitting the endpoint directly using the `jti` field that comes back in the `credential` response from Google, i.e. https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=my_token_here, but it says it is invalid each time, even though I literally just received it from Google each time that I test it.

When I go to [Google’s docs for verifying the token](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token), the example for Python is extremely clear - but since there is no Ruby client, it leads me to the link “[Use one of the Google API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library)”, so I click on the Ruby one which [takes me here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client), which then tells me that I should use [the more modern clients](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby). So then I bounce between those last two links, and within those GitHub repositories I’ve been unable to find anything useful.

I tried using [this `googleauth` gem](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby), but the only useful methods seem to be `Google::Auth::IDTokens.verify_oidc(access_token)` as well as `Google::Auth::IDTokens.verify_iap(access_token)`, but both of those return saying it is an invalid token, and I’m not using OIDC (open ID connect) nor IAP (Identity-aware Proxy), as far as I know, so it makes sense that it returns as invalid.

Any help would be much appreciated - I’m sure other folks have had to verify tokens in a similar manner before using Ruby.